# Unable to store Airflow task objects to a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm trying to **store Airflow task objects in dictionary** as values like the following

```
operator_dict = {}

operator_dict['file-sensor1'] = FileSensor(task_id=file-sensor-1, fs_conn_id='fs_source', filepath=file, poke_interval=30, timeout=300,dag=dag)
```

Printing `operator_dict` dictionary looks like the following

```
{'filetrigger_1': <Task(FileSensor): filetrigger_1>, 'filetrigger_2': <Task(FileSensor): filetrigger_2>, 'datamorphjob_1': <Task(DatabricksRunNowOperator): datamorphjob_1>})
```

I see no error/exception raised in the above step so I assume this is allowed and was able to set operators to a dictionary value and then store that entire dictionary to airflow Variable using

```
Variable.set("my_list", operator_dict)
```

But when I retrieve the same using `Variable.get("my_dict")` I assume it is not able to deserialize the dictionary data properly just like it does with the json list data.

For list anyhow I use something like `ast.literal_eval(Variable.get("workflow"))` and it works but for dictionary, I tried using `eval(Variable.get("my_dict"))` to identify the issue and it throws the following exception.

[image]

Eventually, I want to do `my_dict['filetrigger_1']` and retrieve the `<Task...>` object associated with that and execute it using either of **upstream** / **downstream**

I found it difficult to identify the real problem here

Answer (score 1):

Airflow variables have their values converted to strings before being persisted (you can see it happen in source code of Variable.set: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_modules/airflow/models/variable.html#Variable.set). As you've seen, the string representation of a Task object can't be deserialized back into the original Task object.

The workaround for this is to pass the arguments for the task instead of passing the task itself. I.e.

```
operator_dict['files_sensor1'] = {'task_id': file-sensor-1, ...}}
```

Then, downstream, you would construct the FileSensor via something like

```
sensor = FileSensor(**operator_dict['files_sensor1'])
```

But stepping back a bit: this seems like a weird pattern that could cause a lot of issues. What if you try to rerun a task from a previous DAG and it gets the variables you set from a future DAG? Or vice-versa? I'd strongly recommend that you consider using XCOM variables or finding a way to construct the tasks entirely within their own associated DAG.